# Using Youtube in iPhone

Tags: iphone, youtube, gdata

I have never use youtube api in iPhone ...I tried to use GData but was missed in some steps here are [link](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) ans [tutorial](http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/) ....So never implemented it...

Due to which i used RSS feed and load it on tableView ...
and when user click on any row then the actual webPage opens in WebView and user have to click on the video to run it....

But now i don't want this ....

Can anyone provide me a better solution....
Thanks...

Comment: Answered a similar question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627536/play-youtube-video-in-full-screen

Answer (score 0):

As I have given a brief answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627536/play-youtube-video-in-full-screen)

I am explaining it in detail:

- Put a button of same size and without any background image over your webview.
- When the user presses this button open a new modal view with only a full screen size webview in it.
- Pass the same html string to load the webview (that you were passing in your smaller webview).
- Pass the touches programmatically to the webview like:

  – (void) touchTheWebViewProgrammatically{

  ```
  for(UIView* vw in [webView subviews]){
      if([vw isKindOfClass:[UIButton Class]])
          [vw sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: did not understand your concept of loding 2 webViews;

Comment: @Kumar\ sonu Thats the way I think, it can be done. May be somebody have a better approach :) but haven't found on yet